# Mean-level forecast from rugarch does not match manual calculation

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, garch

I am looking into the `rugarch` package and am trying to understand how the one-step-ahead forecast is calculated.

Specifically, I am fitting an AR(2)-GARCH(1,1) process with a normal distribution to the SP500 return series and would like to use the conditional mean as my one-step-ahead point forecast. The one-step-ahead conditional mean is determined solely by the AR equation of the process and thus is given by the following formula, where $E[\epsilon_{t+1}|F_t]=0$.

$$
E[y_{t+1}|F_t]=\beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t} + \beta_2 y_{t-1} + E[\epsilon_{t+1}|F_t]
$$

The above formula suggest that I should be able to calculate my forecast using the last two observations of the sample and the fitted coefficients. If I do that and compare my result to the one-step-ahead forecast calculated with the in-build method of the `rugarch` package the results differ (0.001278 vs. 0.001205). Does anybody have any suggestions why the results might differ?

```r
library("rugarch")

data(sp500ret)

spec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 0)), 
          variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", 
           garchOrder = c(1,1), submodel = 'GARCH'))
fit  <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = sp500ret)

# In-build Forecast
ugarchforecast(fit, n.ahead = 1)

# Forecast

fit@fit$coef[1:3] %*% matrix(c(1,sp500ret[5522:5523,]), nrow = 3, ncol =1)
```

Comment: Good question. You should have `sp500ret[5523:5522,]` instead of `sp500ret[5522:5523,]` as otherwise $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ get mixed up. But that still does not solve the problem: I get 0.001265279 which is not 0.001278...

Comment: @RichardHardy: Indeed. Thank you for spotting the mistake.

Comment: You have the wrong model equation, it should be $Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (Y_{t-1}-\beta_0) + \beta_2 (Y_{t-2}-\beta_0)+\varepsilon_t$. Then it matches.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, consider posting your comment as an answer. And $\mu$ as in the output seems like a better fitting symbol than $\beta_0$ in this context.